# Как ожидать сообщение от пользователя

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

```
    elif message.text.lower() == "анон":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет введи ID чата в нашей системе, в который ты хочешь отправить сообщение! Его можно узнать написав в чат /info")
```

**Как сделать так, чтобы бот ожидал сообщение и по его приходу понял, что это ID чата ?**

Answer (score 2):

используйте [register_next_step_handler](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py)

```
def test(message):
    a = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ид?')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(a, test_2)


def test_2(message):
    if message.text.isdigit():
        print('это цифры')
```